# Failed to reset MySQL password

Tags: mysql, sql, command-prompt, change-password

Recently I tried to reset mySQL password using command prompt using this instruction https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.7/en/resetting-permissions-windows.html .

I did exactly as in the instruction but my it didn't turn out as how it is supposed to be. It just stopped there after I pressed enter, nothing happened, no errors or warnings or whatsoever. I even tried restarting the server with the new password.

here's the result of the command. like i said, no errors or warnings after i pressed enter. [image: no errors nor warnings]

and here's the error when i try to restart the server with the new password 
[image: error]

i expected this output here (i got this from a youtube video; the guy did exactly the same thing)
[image: expected outcome]

Comment: What did you expect to happen after you'd started `mysqld`? Did you try connecting to server with the new password?

Comment: i expected it to produce some lines like this guy had https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dyc5b3yT2tI&t=268s @mustaccio and yes i tried

Answer (score 2):

Tryout these steps:

1. Stop your MySQL server completely. This can be done from Wamp(if you use it), or start “services.msc” using Run window, and stop the service there.
2. Open your MS-DOS command prompt using “cmd” inside the Run window. Then go to your MySQL bin folder, such as C:\MySQL\bin. Path is different if you use Wamp.
3. Execute the following command in the command prompt:

   mysqld.exe -u root --skip-grant-tables
4. Leave the current MS-DOS command prompt as it is, and open a new MS-DOS command prompt window.
5. Go to your MySQL bin folder again.
6. Enter “mysql” and press enter.
7. You should now have the MySQL command prompt working. Type “use mysql;” so that we switch to the “mysql” database.
8. Execute the following command to update the password:

UPDATE user SET Password = PASSWORD('your_new_passowrd') WHERE User = 'root';
However, you can now run almost any SQL command that you wish.

After you are finished close the first command prompt, and type “exit;” in the second command prompt.

You can now start the MySQL service. That’s it.

Comment: I'm stucked on the third step. I got the same error as the second pic above (sorry too long to paste here) but it is the same error that i got

Comment: So if I get this correct when you type mysqld.exe -u root --skip-grant-tables in cmd you get back an error?

Comment: yes correct. here are part of it >`2019-09-22T17:52:52.473209Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2019-09-22T17:52:52.473603Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013276] [Server] Failed to set datadir to 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\' (OS errno: 2 - No such file or directory)
2019-09-22T17:52:52.516907Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2019-09-22T17:52:52.517871Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete`

Comment: try this out pls --> start > CMD > c:\Program Files\MySQL Server 5.7\bin > mysql -u root -p

Comment: If this doesn't work try run CMD as administrator maybe that will do.

Comment: i tried that out but since i forgot my old password, i tried that with a new password (which i hoped would work but didnt). I got the same error as above when i entered any passwords

Comment: nothing works even if i run cmd as admin.. should i uninstall mysql and install a new one again?

Comment: That might work I was doing a small research and some people fixed this problem by uninstalling and installing mysql. Pls let me know if you did this and it worked or not!